# Solving two dimensional Heat equation PDE in mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation, axisymmetry

I am trying to solve the following equation in Mathematica but I do not know each time it only returns the equation itself instead of solving it. I tried both Dsolve and NDsolve and it was not helping me. Could anyone help me with the correct syntax? There is a symmetry boundary condition there and the equation is in cylindrical r and z and depends on time t too.

```
heat= (1/r)*D[r*T[r, z, t], r] + 
D[T[r, z, t], {z, 2}] == (1/(10^-4))*D[T[r, z, t], t]
NDSolve[{heat, T[0.05, z, 0] == 500, D[T[r, z, t], r] == 0}, 
T, {r, 0.01, 0.05}, {t, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 0.05}]
```

I did the same with Dsolve and no success. If this question is not related to here would you guide me where and how to post it before you deactivate it? 
I added the condition of D[T[r, z, t], r] == 0 because I have a cylinder and it is axisymmetric however I do not know if this is a right assumption since we have heat transfer toward z direction too. thank you.

Comment: I mean, you've only specified one boundary condition. What are the boundary conditions in the `z` direction?

Comment: Is this `T[0.05, z, 0] == 500` an initial or a boundary condition. You can not have both. Either the `0.05` needs to be `r` or the `0` needs to be `t`. Also you'd need to rewrite the `D[T[r, z, t], r] == 0` to `Derivative[1, 0, 0][T][r, z, t] == 0` and specify either `r` or `z`.

Comment: do you really just get the expression returned? I get this error "NDSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables, {T[r,z,t]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined. >>". Can you describe in words what the physical problem is? Your boundary conditions don't make sense.

Comment: @user21 T[0.05, z, 0] == 500 is both boundary and initial condition. I know it is uncommon in regular PDE problems. At time t=0 the whole cylinder has temprature of fivehundred . Is there any better representation for that? Thank you for the suggestion on Derivative[1, 0, 0][T][r, z, t] == 0 but may I ask how that is different from what I wrote i.e D[T[r, z, t], r] == 0? It seems to me they are the same.

Comment: @march you are right. I was not sure how to write it. On top and bottom of my cylinder surface I have insulation and also the initial condition of fivehundered on the surface. For the insulation I think I should put Derivative[0, 1, 0][T][r, 0, t] == 0 and Derivative[0, 1, 0][T][r, 0.05, t] == 0. Am I correct?

Comment: You also need to supply an initial condition which is the initial temperature function within your material.

Comment: @george2079 I have a cylinder that is surrounded by another cylinder. Top and bottom there is insulation. The outer cylinder is like electric heat generator to keep the inner cylinder warm. At t=0 the inner cylinder has a fivehundered temprature fixed all over it. I want to see the temprature distribution of the inner cylinder after 10 seconds.

Comment: @march Is this T[r, z, 0] == 500 better instead of T[0.05, z, 0] == 500 or I should have both? (Sorry I am not with my Desktop right now to test with mathematica)

Comment: I can't tell you what your boundary conditions and initial conditions need to be. It sounds to me like you need to first completely specify your problem *mathematically* and consistently before you try to code it up in *Mathematica*. Once you have all of that sorted, looking up the proper syntax for `NDSolve`, and you should be able to put it all together. As it stands, this is more of a mathematics question and less of a *Mathematica* question.

Comment: @march Yes, I agree. However, that is all I know of this problem.  What other forum you suggest me to visit and ask?

Comment: @Silas, you need to specify where the derivative of `D` is supposed to have a specific value (r or z need a value); you can not directly do that with `D` but you can with `Derivative`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in 3D. I am too lazy to think about the 2D case

```
h = 10;
r = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}];
ifun = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y, z], t] == 
     Laplacian[u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], 
    DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y, z] == If[t < 1, 500*t + 500, 1000], 
     0 < z < h], u[0, x, y, z] == 500}, 
   u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, y, z} \[Element] r];
SliceContourPlot3D[ifun[5, x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] r, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Boxed -> False, Axes -> None]
```

[image]

The model is the following: The top and bottom are Neumann zero boundary conditions. The boundary is a DirichletCondition that is initially at 500 and then ramped up to 1000 during the first second. Hope this is a starting point. Please have a look at the documentation for `DirichletCondition` and `NeumannValue` for how to model different physical phenomena.

**Update**

[Here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/solve-axisymmetric-pdes.html) is an example of solving an axis-symmetric PDE.

Answer to a question from the comments: `{x,y,z}` is element of the region `r`

Comment: thank you very much, this is very helpful and close to what I needed. Would you explain what does \[Element] r do? I could not understand the documentation in Mathematica.

Comment: @Silas, see update.